# Magento 2 - Importing Configurable Products problem!

Tags: magento2

I am stuck at importing a configurable product from a CSV file. Take a look at it below:

```
sku,supplier_number,genuine,name,url_key,brand,price,qty,attribute_set_code,product_type,meta_title,meta_description,meta_keyword,short_description,description,specifications,categories,make,model,year_from,year_to,weight,length,width,height,base_image,small_image,thumbnail_image,swatch_image,additional_images,visibility,configurable_variations,configurable_variation_labels
10100033_Mercedes_Sprinter,BSG90900010,,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",,BSG,200,100,Default,simple,base,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",,,Category/Replacement Parts/Body Parts,Mercedes,Sprinter,2006,2016,2.2,35,43,25,,,,,,Not Visible Individually,,
10100033_VW_Crafter,BSG90900010,,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",,BSG,200,100,Default,simple,base,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",,,Category/Replacement Parts/Body Parts,VW,Crafter,2006,2016,2.2,35,43,25,,,,,,Not Visible Individually,,
10100033,,,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",mercedes-sprinter-vw-crafter-mirror-rh-door-complete-asembly-long-wire-10-2006-10100033,BSG,200,100,Default,configurable,"Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006","Mercedes Sprinter, VW Crafter, Mirror, RH Door, Complete asembly, long wire, 10/2006",,,Category/Replacement Parts/Body Parts,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Catalog, Search","sku=10100033_Mercedes_Sprinter,make=Mercedes,model=Sprinter|sku=10100033_VW_Crafter,make=VW,model=Crafter","make=Make,model=Model"
```

This configurable product's SKU is 10100033. It links 2 simple products with SKUs 10100033_Mercedes_Sprinter and 10100033_VW_Crafter respectively. But after the import, the Catalog shows that 2 of 3 products imported are wrong -> 
[image]
 (image link that describes the issue)

One more thing that in the configurable product detail page, the attribute order is wrong:
[image]

Here is the link to that product: http://test.rainstormstudio.com.au/machinehead/index.php/vw-volkswagen-crafter-mercedes-sprinter-indicator-lense-for-rh-mirror-10-2006-10400001.html